# Java spring url changes and adds model

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have page in my web application:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/form/prod/create/0
```

which has a form attributes of

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/user/form/prod/create/${formProd.formHeader.headerId}" ></c:url>
<form:form id="formSubmit" action="${addAction}" modelAttribute="formProd" class="form-horizontal" method="get">

-- Codes for inputs and submit button --

</form:form>
```

Once the button is clicked it will go through this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/user/form/prod/{type}/{headerId}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView formCreateView(@Validated @ModelAttribute("formProd") FormProd formProd, BindingResult result
        , ModelMap model, Principal principal, @PathVariable(value="headerId") Long headerId, @PathVariable(value="type") String type
        , HttpServletRequest request) {

-- Do some stuff AND return to the same url page http://localhost:8080/user/form/prod/create/0

return new ModelAndView(AuthenticationBase.JSP_USER_FORM_PROD, model);
}
```

The issue is the url changes to:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/form/prod/create/0?formHeader.status=DRAFT&formHeader.prodDate=&formHeader.startDateTime=&formHeader.endDateTime=&lookupName=KMM1++++++++++++++++++++++++++&formHeader.line=&formHeader.machine=&formHeader.prodCategoryId=10&formHeader.product=&formHeader.outputMeasureUnitId=13&formHeader.unitPerCarton=&formHeader.standardMachineSpeed=0.0&formHeader.intervalMins=&formHeader.sessionId=
```

Which also includes my model.  Since the url is different, If I click or submit the form again it now shows "whitelabel error page":

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Sep 03 11:41:58 SGT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Any idea why the url changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to add the data on click of a button and here you are using the GET method that's why your URL gets change every time when you click on the button.

**modify code to below it should work**

```
   <c:url var="addAction" value="/user/form/prod/create/${formProd.formHeader.headerId}" ></c:url>
    <form:form id="formSubmit" action="${addAction}" modelAttribute="formProd" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">

-- Codes for inputs and submit button --

</form:form>
```

**Controller code change**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/user/form/prod/{type}/{headerId}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView formCreateView(@Validated @ModelAttribute("formProd") FormProd formProd, BindingResult result
        , ModelMap model, Principal principal, @PathVariable(value="headerId") Long headerId, @PathVariable(value="type") String type
        , HttpServletRequest request) {

-- Do some stuff AND return to the same URL page http://localhost:8080/user/form/prod/create/0

return new ModelAndView(AuthenticationBase.JSP_USER_FORM_PROD, model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the by default functionality for GET type mappings.

*The GET Method
In GET method the data is sent as URL parameters that are usually strings of name and value pairs separated by ampersands (&). In general, a URL with GET data will look like this:
Example :
http://www.example.com/action?name=Sam&weight=55*

Change method type it post and also form method to post and it works.

Change

```
method = RequestMethod.GET
```

To

```
method = RequestMethod.POST
```

And in view page change form type to POST.

```
method="POST"
```